# Where can I find the current ProvidedTypes.fs API?

Tags: f#, type-providers

The last Type Provider I wrote just after F# 3.0 was released, and I used the `ProvidedTypes.fs(i)` files that came with the sample pack.

These files are quite old by now, and I wondered if there are more recent versions.

By googling alone I came up with six different versions. Where can I find the current, official version of `ProvidedTypes.fs` and `ProvidedTypes.fsi`?

Moreover, I heard that generated types are now easier to implement. Is this funtionality already inside newer versions of those files?

Comment: I would imagine the one on F#.data would be reasonably new https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/tree/master/src/CommonProviderImplementation

Comment: The starter pack is maintained at https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.StarterPack

Comment: Thanks @MaxMalook, that looks like the best option, if you could promote this comment to an answer, I could accept it :)

Comment: @JohnPalmer, thank you. I had already found that version, but wasn't sure if it was any good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested by Nikon, here is the comment promoted to an answer :)

The starter pack is maintained at https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.StarterPack

Comment: This is the best place to go, but FWIW it has not diverged *too* dramatically form the latest version in the sample pack.  Sample pack was updated just 8 months ago.